# I have this simple form that I want to input in data to a javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

This is my first time working with javascript and what i am looking to do is submit the from with your name and that would go to the javascript and display your name.

This is what I have now. The Name will go in the var myName that is getting submitted and grabbed by the "name =form.name.value"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/hour-of-code/js/alphabet.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" height="500" width="1000"></canvas>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/hour-of-code/js/bubbles.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript">
    function mynamesubmit(form) {
      var red = [0, 100, 63];
      var orange = [40, 100, 60];
      var green = [75, 100, 40];
      var blue = [196, 77, 55];
      var purple = [280, 50, 60];
      name = from.name.value;
      var myName = name;
      var letterColors = [red, orange, green, blue, red, green, purple];
      if (6 < 4) {
        bubbleShape = "circle";
      } else {
        bubbleShape = "square";
      }
      drawName(myName, letterColors);
      bounceBubbles()
    }
  </script>
  <form id="my-form" action="" method="Get">
    <h2>Enter Your name and move your cusror over your name. Try other names and see what happens.</h2>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name" value=" " id="name" />
    <button name="button1" onclick "mynamesubmit(this.form)">Go</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Edit: 20150512
What I want is when you put your name in form that it will display on myCanvas. I can not find a way where I can have input that changes the javascript. With my coding, if i put it like this it displays my name fine, but there is no way where i can change it because it is written in the code.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/hour-of-code/js/alphabet.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" height="500" width="1000"></canvas>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/hour-of-code/js/bubbles.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript">
    var red = [0, 100, 63];
    var orange = [40, 100, 60];
    var green = [75, 100, 40];
    var blue = [196, 77, 55];
    var purple = [280, 50, 60];

    var myName = "Gunner1714";
    var letterColors = [red, orange, green, blue, red, green, purple];
    if (6 < 4) {
      bubbleShape = "circle";
    } else {
      bubbleShape = "square";
    }
    drawName(myName, letterColors);
    bounceBubbles()
  </script>
  <form id="my-form" action="" method="Get">
    <h2>Enter Your name and move your cusror over your name. Try other names and see what happens.</h2>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name" value=" " id="name" />
    <button name="button1" onclick "mynamesubmit(this.form)">Go</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I understand that you got the name in the name variable, now what do you want to do with it?

Comment: If your task is to display name from the input field and not to process it at the server end then you need not no submit the form..

Comment: Looks like you want to prevent the form from submitting, please describe your problem in more detail. And explain what is going wrong in your code.

Comment: I want to have an input field that you can put your name and when you click go it displays it on myCanvas

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question with a prompt. When you go to the page it will ask you your age. Thanks to everyone.

```html
var red = [0, 100, 63];
    var orange = [40, 100, 60];
    var green = [75, 100, 40];
    var blue = [196, 77, 55];
    var purple = [280, 50, 60];

    var myName = prompt("What is your Name") ;
    var letterColors = [red, orange, green, blue, red, green, purple];
    if("myName".length <= 8) {
        bubbleShape = "circle";
    }
    else {
        bubbleShape = "square";
    }
    drawName(myName, letterColors);
    bounceBubbles()
```